# Collapse / Merge multiple rows with non empty cells/ values

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, summarize

I am trying to merge two rows by a similar group which I did by looking at different questions on stack overflow ([Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w), [Qestion2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225596/merge-multiple-rows-into-one-using-r), [Question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69868520/how-to-combine-fields-with-duplicate-keys-to-comma-separated)). All these questions stated what I want but I also have some empty fields in my data frame and I don't want to merge them.  I only want to merge the similar/duplicate rows based on `Col1` that contain values and not **empty** or `NA`. I use below code but it also merges cells that are **empty** or `NA`.

```
merge_my_rows <- df %>%
  group_by(Col1) %>%
  summarise(Col2 = paste(Col2, collapse = ","))
```

Below please is the sample **df** and Output df that I want.

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| F212 | ALICE |
| D23 | John |
| C64 | NA |
| F212 | BOB |
| C64 | NA |
| D23 | JohnY |
| D19 | Marquis |

**Output df**

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| F212 | ALICE, BOB |
| D23 | John, JohnY |
| C64 | NA |
| C64 | NA |
| D19 | Marquis |

Answer (score 1):

You can set a new grouping column, `na.grp`, that gives each `NA` in `Col2` a unique number and gives those non-NA elements a common number.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Col1, na.grp = ifelse(is.na(Col2), cumsum(is.na(Col2)), 0)) %>%
  summarise(Col2 = paste(Col2, collapse = ", "), .groups = "drop") %>%
  select(-na.grp)

# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#   Col1  Col2       
#   <chr> <chr>      
# 1 C64   NA         
# 2 C64   NA         
# 3 D19   Marquis    
# 4 D23   John, JohnY
# 5 F212  ALICE, BOB
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- read.table(text = "
Col1  Col2
F212  ALICE
D23   John
C64   NA
F212  BOB
C64   NA
D23   JohnY
D19   Marquis", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reframe`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  reframe(Col2 = if(all(is.na(Col2))) Col2 else toString(Col2[!is.na(Col2)])
      , .by = "Col1")
```

-output

```
Col1        Col2
1 F212  ALICE, BOB
2  D23 John, JohnY
3  C64        <NA>
4  C64        <NA>
5  D19     Marquis
```